# Windows 10: How to remove unwelcome hidden networks

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking

I have 3 networks showing up which I have not selected. Worse still they have "connect automatically" checked. If you try to unconnect them, they immediately go back to connect automatically. If you try to remove them through the "network and internet" page, they do not appear under "manage known networks".  I do have a virtual machine installed but this should not have it's own dedicated wireless network. And if it did, it would be named something I would recognise.

How do I get rid of these networks. I feel like i have been hacked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. Uncheck “Connect automatically “ and close the connection.
2. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator by clicking on the Start icon, scroll down to Windows System, then right click on Command Prompt to choose **Run as Administrator**.

Then  `netsh wlan show profiles` to see your current profiles

Then `netsh wlan delete profile name=`*profile name*  for every profile you do not want.

Restart and test your wireless

If there are still networks you are trying to connect to, try a Wireless Scanner to see them; see

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-discover-hidden-wireless-network/

Then, having discovered them with one of these scanners, hide them from your computer, following:

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/hide-neighborhood-wifi-ssid-computer/

Comment: The rogue networks do not show up under wlan show profiles. What really troubles me is that they all have connect automatically checked, and it is impossible to disable the check mark. I ran a full deep scan with windows 10 and everything came up clean.

Comment: If I try to connect to one of these networks it asks for the "network security key"

Comment: I have added variations of the tools to help you see them (wireless scanners) then hide them from your home computer (netsh variation)

Comment: Great job, thank you very much. After downloading the inSSIDer I could see that these accounts were from my neighbours. So I blocked them all and white listed my own. Thanks !

Comment: Great feedback.  I have inSSider here and can see what is going on around me. Wireless scanners are great for that. Thank you.